# get all of the user media with Instagram API return empty parameter

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I'm in a problem with Instagram API and `min_id` and `max_id` parameters. 
My authenticated user have over 100 medias but when I try to get another part of the user medias over his first 20 medias it get empty `data` JSON parameter.

for example, my first media id is `1173958321567246146_177152120` and the last one is `1070424319045215888_177152120` but when I try to send the request with this URI I get an empty array:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/177152120/media/recent/?max_id=1070424319045215888_177152120&access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are in sandbox mode? sandbox mode is limited to last 20 media items in API response.

Here is more details about sandbox mode: https://www.instagram.com/developer/sandbox/

> To help you develop and test your app, the users and media available
>   in Sandbox mode are real Instagram data (i.e. what is normally visible
>   in the Instagram app), but with the following conditions:
>
> - Apps in sandbox are restricted to 10 users
> - Data is restricted to the    10 users and the 20 most recent media    from each of those users
> - Reduced API rate limits